# "Can't use function return value in write context" error

Tags: php

I have "Can't use function return value in write context" keep returning . I saw the solutions in the other answer but I seems to me that it doesn't apply to my case. 
Can you tell me wheres the problem.

```
<?php
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
    $_SESSION['myusername']=$myusername;
    $_SESSION('mypassword')=$mypassword; 
    header("location:izmeniEvent.php");
} else {
    echo "Pogresna lozinka";
}

/*
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:izmeniEvent.php");
}
*/
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$_SESSION('mypassword')=$mypassword;`

Should be square brackets. A simple typo.